# Make Migrations on Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have a Django model which looks like this

```
class RedUsers(BaseModel):
    user_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    red_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Red Users"
```

I want to add a new field

```
activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
```

I already have lots of data in this model and I can't drop the table, so I need to make migration manually.

I have tried adding the model from my **0001_initial.py** file without luck

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration): 
    initial = True

    dependencies = [] 

    operations = [ 
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='RedUsers',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('modified', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('user_email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, null=True)),
                ('user_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)),
                ('red_id', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)),
                ('active', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name_plural': 'RED Users',
            },
        ),
         migrations.AddField(
            model_name='redusers',
            name='activation_key',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=40, null=True, verbose_name='activation key'),
        ),
    ]
```

When I run 
`python manage.py migrate`

It says Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.

I don't know what else to do

Comment: Well since you likely *already* migrated. Django added the name of that migration file to the table, and hence it thinks the migration is fully done. I think it is better to simply remove the `AddField`, and run `makemigrations`. It will make a second file, with another migration name.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a new field
>
> ```
> activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
> ```
>
> I already have lots of data in this model and I can't drop the table,
>   so I need to make migration manually.

You don't need to. If you run `makemigrations` a second time, Django will detect that you added a field, and will make an extra migration file to add that field to the model.

You thus better here remove the `AddField` migration object from the migration file, and run `python3 manage.py makemigrations`.

It will make a new file, likely something that starts with `0002_….py`, and it will take the first migration as dependency.

You can then run `python3 manage.py` migrate, and Django will add the field at the database level, and insert the name of the migration in the migration table.

Comment: @zaddyn00b: yes, you *first* need to remove the `AddField` from the original migration. If you add that, Django will, when you run `makemigrations` think it was already added by a previous migration. Please do not start editing the migrations that are constructed automatically.

Comment: I took that out, I am running Django==1.11.10 on python 2, but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: @zaddyn00b: did you remove the `*.pyc` files (compiled binaries)?